# QTableView - how to prevent selection change

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have QTableView with custom table model. User can select row in the table and in specific situations I want to prevent change of the current selection.

Reselection of previously selected row is not an ideal solution (signals about the change are emited).

So what is the easies solution?

Is there some option I do not see?

Do I need to subclass QTableView?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution you were happy with?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a View not selectable with [QAbstractItemView::setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop)

And you can do it in a per item basis too, using Qt::ItemIsSelectable

[Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex & index) const [virtual]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags)

Edit (comments):

You have a custom model, so you can set a current row member variable. then, override flags:

```
Qt::ItemFlags YourModel::flags(const QModelIndex & index) const
{
  if( _current_row  > 0 && index.row()  != _current_row)
  {
    return QAbstractItemModel::flags() | ^Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
  }
  else
  {
    return QAbstractItemModel::flags() | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
  }

}
```

Of course, dindt tried, but you get the idea.

Updated so, if you set current_row to -1, all are selectable

Comment: This works only partialy. It does not allow to select another row, but when I click my currently selected row is unselected. I want to keep my original selection.

Comment: Well, i gave you 2 options. With the second, overriding flags(), you can make every item not selectable but current row's. I will update my post with an example.

Comment: I understand and I tested this solution - but as I said - in the moment when I click on a row which is not selectable I lose my original selection.

Comment: Ok, then i think the only way must be filtering the click events for the viewport

Answer (score -1):

You can reselect the previously selected row.  In the signal handler, call blocksignals(true) before reselection and then call blocksignals(false) to allow signalling again.

Comment: But the selection changed signal would already be fired for the first change (not for the reseledction though)